# VS intellisense not working on solution with multiple projects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am working on a .NET Core/C# solution that contains multiple projects. I have done so before but for this one I set up everything through a remote server in a linux terminal. Once all my projects were created and pushed to GitHub, I pulled to my local machine. Problem I am running into is that intellisense is not working at all in any project in my solution. I am wondering if I set up everything correctly or if there is something I am missing. Below is some screenshots of my directory and one screenshot of VS.

root dir from repo
[image: root dir from repo]

1 dir down into BlabberApp folder
[image: 1 dir down into BlabberApp folder]

2nd dir down into BlabberApp.DomainTest
[image: 2nd dir down into BlabberApp.DomainTest]

What is shown in VS when I open root dir
[image: What is shown in VS when I open root dir]

What is shown in VS when I open solution file
[image: What is shown in VS when I open solution file]

I have tried opening using open file for: .csproj file, .cs file, as well as open folder for various folders that hold my separate projects. I also tried to open folder to the BlabberApp folder which contains the folders that hold my .sln as well as the folders that hold all my separate projects. I need intellisense to recognize references some projects have with each other. I also need it to recognize my tests to properly test everything. One thing peculiar I found is when I open the .sln file it shows in the solution explorer that 0 projects are loaded. Also none of my tests are recognized in the test explorer (I have tried cleaning and building the sln with no changes showing in test explorer).

I have also gone through the steps of going to tools -> options -> text editor -> c# -> intellisense to check/uncheck the boxes under completion lists. Any advice would be helpful! Thanks

Comment: hi @Erck You told that opening the sln file does not open or load other projects in solution explorer. But your screenshot is stating not so. I am seeing every project is loaded in solution explorer. Can you provide screenshot when you have no project while opened sln? and how did you fix it?

Comment: I added another screenshot to clarify. The last photo is when I open the solution file, the second to last screenshot is when I open the root directory of the repo.

Comment: can you delete the .vs folder and try opening double clicking the solution file?

Comment: Just tried that. Didn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: can you paste the sln file's code in pastebin?

Comment: Sure. Here's the link. https://pastebin.com/8ifc6VPA

Comment: it seems that any of your project is not listed in your solution file. can you follow this? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MaciejGudanowicz.AddMultipleProjectsToSolution and let me know that it works.

Comment: Yes that worked thank you so much!!

Comment: please accept the answer for future reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems any of your projects are not listed in your solution. Somehow they unloaded from the solution. You can add the projects one by one in the solution. Or you can take help of a plugin that will add all projects from the solution folder at once. please add them by the following step:

1. Add [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MaciejGudanowicz.AddMultipleProjectsToSolution) VS extension
2. Right-click on the solution and click on Add multiple projects
3. check Add solution folder
4. Click Load Projects From Folder
5. Select the solution directory
6. Select all projects
7. Click start

please follow the link instructions for more details.